# PouchDB & ANGULARJS - best way to design

Tags: javascript, angularjs, synchronization, client-server, pouchdb

I would like to know the best way to use pouchDB in my app with AngularJS.

What I want from pouchDB is to build a database replicated from a remote DB on start and then it must listen for changes and update the UI together with the controller data.

Answer (score 0):

Well, rather than AngularJS, I recommend ReactJS + MobX + PouchDB. I have implemented this tech stack and I'm quite satisfied.

MobX has [a module](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react) to work with ReactJS. MobX listens to changes on app state with `observables` and updates UI with `observers`. Watch [this video](https://youtu.be/_q50BXqkAfI) to see a how it works.